# get range address of merger cells using excel office api javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins, office365api, excel-addins

```
var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var range = sheet.getUsedRange();

range.load(["rowCount", "columnCount", "values", "address",""]);
```

Comment: we can easily merge a specific range of cell but the problem is i cannot get the range address of already merge cells.

Comment: The range address of merge cell can still get, do you mean the address is not updated after the merge? Could you please share your scenario? or share a gist, I can have a look